# Unable to display the content of {% block content %}{% endblock %} in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, web, flask-login

My page is empty no matter what code I put into the {%block content%}

Only the title of the web can be changed. Look at the image, please. It's blank.

I used a template from the guide.
What's the problem? The HTML doesn't work.
Can someone help me, please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzSs8.png)

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    
    {% block content %}
        <h2>Bienvenue !</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rhoncus 
            massa non tortor. Vestibulum diam diam, posuere in viverra in, 
            ullamcorper et libero. Donec eget libero quis risus congue imperdiet ac 
            id lectus. Nam euismod cursus arcu, et consequat libero ullamcorper sit 
            amet.
        </p>
    {% endblock %}
```

> Here is the base.html code:

````
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            <link
             rel="stylesheet"
             href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
             integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
             crossorigin="anonymous"
            />
            <link
             rel="stylesheet"
             href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
             crossorigin="anonymous"
            />
            <title>{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}</title>
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <button
                  class="navbar-toggler"
                  type="button"
                  data-toggle="collapse"
                  data-target="#navbar"
                >
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                  <div class="navbar-nav">
                  
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="/">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="logout" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                 
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/login">Login</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="signUp" href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
                   
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nav>
          
              <script
                src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
              ></script>
              <script
                src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
              ></script>
              <script
                src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
              ></script>
      
              <script
              type="text/javascript"
              src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"
              ></script>
        </body>>
    </html>```
````

Answer (score 1):

There is no `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` in your base.html file. Add those lines in your base.html file. I guess you want the content to be displayed after the navbar, then paste those lines after the navbar section. I hope it helps!